# How to make sure BindingSource.DataSource takes connections information from App.Config file and not the hardcoded values?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, app-config

I have a Winform where I have connection.config file where I get my database connection.

I also have forms where I have dataGridView and that is bound to a DataSet that are in .XSD file.  I used that while i was creating an application. Now when I publish to server for live, it still displays data from hardcoded values of DataSet rather than taking it from App.config (connection.config) file. How do I make sure all of my connections comes from that one example connection string that are in connection.config file?

e.g.

```cs
this.tbl_StatusTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDataSet.Tbl_Status);
```

Above line of code does not connect to App.config files connection!

I can add another `DatSources->DataSet` and bind existing data-binding to this live database connection's dataSet rather than local dB. but I want no manual work while deploying the application to the server.

```cs
this.tbl_StatusTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDataSet.Tbl_Status)
```

How can this be come from App.Config?

```cs
 this.tbl_TableAdapter.Update(this.DBDataSet);
```

How do I convert above statement that link to `App.COnfig` connection?

Comment: `TableAdapter` reads the connection string from connection strings section of app.config. If the app.config file is not present, it refers to the default value which you have in the settings class in `DefaultSettingValueAttribute` of the connection string property.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate to [How to set a table adapter's connection string (to one that is dynamically set).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047353/how-to-set-a-table-adapters-connection-string-to-one-that-is-dynamically-set)
 It includes XSD vs App.Config settings and resolution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and error i found below

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 this.MyTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[MyconnStrName];
    this.MyTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;

}

Those two lines of code needs to be put very first on form load event and rest it connects to a database that is in App.config file rather than what is in Property settings.

Comment: I still wonder how to change the connection string that is in Properties.Settings file, any comments on that is welcome. I tried to change Settings but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what do you mean...
you need to add this reference : System. Configuration
then add below code:

OledbConnection MyConnection = new OledbConnection() ;
//this connect to access database.. you can use any database type

MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManger. ConnectionStrings["ConnectionName"].ToString();

Comment: HI I am again Asking on this similar issue. Can someone explain to me , even if I change my database name on external configuration file. called "connection.config"  , why Winform project still looks for connection string in  PROJECTNAME.Designer.cs file ( in Project property  ).  have a scenario where I have to change the connection string after I deploy the project with different name on Initial Catalog.But simply updating external config file does not work!